# Java remove diacritic

Tags: java, diacritics

I am trying to make function which will remove diacritic(dont want to use Normalizer on purpose).Function looks like

```
private static String normalizeCharacter(Character curr) {
    String sdiac = "áäčďéěíĺľňóôőöŕšťúůűüýřžÁÄČĎÉĚÍĹĽŇÓÔŐÖŔŠŤÚŮŰÜÝŘŽ";
    String bdiac = "aacdeeillnoooorstuuuuyrzAACDEEILLNOOOORSTUUUUYRZ";
    char[] s = sdiac.toCharArray();
    char[] b = bdiac.toCharArray();
    String ret;
    for(int i = 0; i < sdiac.length(); i++){
        if(curr == s[i])
            curr = b[i];
    }
    ret = curr.toString().toLowerCase();
    ret = ret.replace("\n", "").replace("\r","");
    return ret;
}
```

funcion is called like this(every charracter from file is sent to this function)

```
private static String readFile(String fName) {

    File f = new File(fName);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    try{

        FileInputStream fStream = new FileInputStream(f);
        Character curr;
        while(fStream.available() > 0){
            curr = (char) fStream.read();
            sb.append(normalizeCharacter(curr));
            System.out.print(normalizeCharacter(curr));
        }
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

file `text.txt` contains this:  `ľščťžýáíéúäôň` and i expect `lcstzyaieuaon`in return from program but insted of expected string i get this `¾è yaieuaoò`. I know that problem is somewhere in encoding but dont know where. Any ideas ?

Comment: Hint on code quality: names like sdiac, bdiac, ... are horrible. Give the things names that tell what they are. Just by changing the names you could make your code much more readable! And for example, why not turn s and b into constants? (So that there is no need to create arrays and throw those away any time this method is called) [ and I assume this method might be called ... well, very often?!]

Comment: Variable names is thing of my language and this is just testing phase so speed of code is not important now(at least for me). There is just 10 lines of code i believe every1 will understand it. Anyway your post does not solve my problem. But thx

Comment: You wrote this code here to be **read** by other people. So you think it doesn't make a difference if it is easy or hard to read? Like "those other people can do work for me, so hey, why should I make their life easier".
Maybe you better think again if such a mindset is the best starter for a conversion. It is even in your very own interest: you want people to focus on your **problem**; not on understanding the source code. The easier the code is to read, the more people will fully read it in order to help you. The harder it is to read, the more people will turn away and not bother.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to convert bytes into characters.

However, the character `ľ` is not represented as a single byte. Its unicode representation is U+013E, and its UTF-8 representation is C4 BE. Thus, it is represented by two bytes. The same is true for the other characters.

Suppose the encoding of your file is UTF-8. Then you read the byte value `C4`, and then you convert it to a `char`. This will give you the character U+00C4 (Ä), *not* U+013E. Then you read the `BE`, and it is converted to the character U+00BE (¾).

So don't confuse bytes and characters. Instead of using the `InputStream` directly, you should wrap it with a `Reader`. A `Reader` is able to read charecters based on the encoding it is created with:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(
                                new FileInputStream(f), StandardCharsets.UTF_8
                            )
                        );
```

Now, you'll be able to read characters or even whole lines and the encoding will be done directly.

```
int readVal;
while ( ( readVal = reader.read() ) != -1 ) {
    curr = (char)readVal;
    // ... the rest of your code
}
```

Remember that you are still reading an `int` if you are going to use `read()` without parameters.

Comment: yeah, totally forgot that read returns int... thanks for pointing that out :)